# Epsilon delta proof in Complex variables

Tags: complex-analysis

I am having big difficulty with this problem ; although the book I am working with gives several similar examples :Problem :Using epsilon delta prove that

$$
\lim_{z \rightarrow 1+i} \frac{z^2-z+1-i}{z^2-2z+2} = 1-\frac{i}{2}
$$

I can see that a factor of $z-i-1$ cancells from top and bottom , but it does not help......

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Hint:

$$
z^2 - z + 1-i = (z+i)(z-i) - (z+i) = (z+i)(z-i-1)
$$
$$
z^2 - 2z +2 = (z-1-i)(z-1+i)
$$

**Update:**

The above simplifies to 
$$
\frac{z+i}{z-1+i}
$$

now we need to estimate $|\frac{z+i}{z-1+i} - (1-\frac{i}{2})|$

$$
|\frac{z+i}{z-1+i} - (1-\frac{i}{2})| = |\frac{\frac{i}{2}(z-1-i)}{z-1+i}| = \frac{\frac{1}{2}|z-1-i|}{|z-1+i|}
$$

and now we look at $|z-1+i|$

$$
|z-1+i| = |2i + z-1-i| > 2-|z-1-i|
$$

for $|z-1-i| < \delta$:

$$
|\frac{z+i}{z-1+i} - (1-\frac{i}{2})| = \frac{\frac{1}{2}|z-1-i|}{|z-1+i|} < \frac{\frac{1}{2}\delta}{2-\delta} = \frac{\delta}{4-2\delta}
$$
in the inequality above we assumed that $2-\delta>0$ but let's wait with this a little.

for this inequality to hold:
$$
\frac{\delta}{4-2\delta} < \epsilon
$$

we need to take $\delta < \frac{4\epsilon}{1+2\epsilon}$ and to ensure that $2-\delta>0$ we take $\delta < min(1, \frac{4\epsilon}{1+2\epsilon})$

Comment: Thanks for your response , but I have done this computation and it does not help...All we get is a cancellation of factors from top and bottom , then what??

Comment: @herashefat please see my update

Comment: Thanks for your detailed response ,I clearly understand now.....